# ipython starts slow, is there a way to accelerate it?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, macos, ubuntu, ipython

I noticed that under ubuntu ipython starts really quickly, almost as fast as python itself.

While under Windows or Mac, it starts really slow. Is there a way to make it better?

Comment: I tried running ipython on my iMac and you are correct, iPython starts slowly. But quitting ipython and starting again was quick.  I don't know what it was about 1st start that made it so slow.